# dpdk mempool allocates way more than necessary

Tags: c, linux, dpdk

I have a linux app which uses dpdk mempools. I am trying to allocate a mempool with 8000000 objects of 24 bytes. When running without `MEMPOOL_F_NO_CACHE_ALIGN` in the mempool creation it allocated 1688 megabytes of eal memory, about 10 times more than necessary. When I added `MEMPOOL_F_NO_CACHE_ALIGN` it was reduced to 512 megabytes which also more than twice as necessary. How can I reduce this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there’s not much you can do. Each memory pool object has a header, which has pointers to:

1. Next object.
2. Memory pool the object belongs to.
3. IO/physical address.

See: 
http://doc.dpdk.org/api/structrte__mempool__objhdr.html

Plus internally memory pool stores a circular buffer, which is roughly another pointer per object. So, the per-object overhead is much more than the data you’re trying to store in each object.

If we don’t care about physical address, etc, and all we need is to be able to store those 24 bytes fast an efficient, we nigh use just the circular buffer ([rte_ring](https://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__ring_8h.html)) with an flat array of small objects. The overhead will be ~8 bytes per object in this case.

The performance will be lower, since memory pool implements internal per-core cache.

If it’s still too much, you should look into other non-DPDK data structures.

Or store buckets of objects. Say, 100 objects per bucket will make the overhead effectively ~100 times lower.